# Where is the `Hide or Show debug area` icon in Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, console, xcode12

Recently I shifted from Xcode 11.7 to Xcode 12.

But in Xcode 12, I'm missing one icon which used to `show or hide the debug area(console area)`.

In Xcode 11.7, the icon was in top left corner of the IDE.

[image]
(Here is the colored one)

Now in Xcode 12, there is only one icon in there.

[image]

Do you have any idea where is the **show or hide the debug area(console area)** icon can be found in Xcode 12?

Answer (score 20):

I believe that button was removed. You can open on the menu, "View" -> "Debug Area" -> "Activate Console"

[image]

Comment: +1 for `I believe that button was removed.` its right. Now only way to open is keyboard shortcut or from `view->Debug area`

Comment: This is a huge UI/usability issue in Xcode 12. Let's hope they'll fix this soon! The hide/show toggle button is still there on the bottom after debugging, but when you click to hide it, the whole button is gone too. So the only way to get it back during not-runtime is navigating a long way through menu or through some obscure shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the keyboard shortcut: `Command` + `Shift` + `Y`.

This will both hide and show the bottom debug area.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the button "Hide/show the debug area"**

[image: Here is the button "Hide/show the debug area"]

**EDIT:**

You can also trigger the console visibility with these hotkeys:

**Show:**
`Shift + Command + C`

**Hide:**
`Shift + Command + Y`

P.S: Actually, XCode shows the hotkeys as being the ones written above, but in reality you can trigger hide & show both with just 1 hotkey: `Shift + Command + Y`

Comment: In Xcode 12, after clicking that button, it'll hide the whole `debug area` including that button. Then how can you'll show the `debug area` again when there will be no button?

Comment: Interesting: if you close the `debug area` with this button, it indeed will hide the whole bar with all the buttons, but once you build your project again, and it starts on the device, the debug area automatically becomes active again and you see the buttons again :D That is some weird UX from Xcode.

Comment: it seems buggy at screen 15"

Answer (score 1):

Command + Shift + C is the default keyboard shortcut

Comment: I know the keyboard shortcut, but i really like that handy icon in a visible state

Comment: I prefer `Command` + `Shift` + `Y` (it toggles the debug area instead of only showing it)